# How to prevent second run of function when using scope.watch in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If i have a simple watch function in AngularJS like :

```
$scope.$watch("myfynnyPropperty", function(updatedproperty){

console.log(updatedproperty);

})
```

console will print out twice, are there anyway to prevent this?

i know that i can set a variable outside which is going to check if console already have printed "updatedproperty", but is it really the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the value has changed:

```
$scope.$watch("myfynnyPropperty", function(newValue, oldValue){
  if(newValue !== oldValue){
    console.log(newValue);
  }
});
```

Comment: oh i didnt knew that i could check for the oldvalue

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean. Why is it happening? is a good question to track down. You can check in the function if newVal === oldVal, or if newVal is null, etc.

```
$scope.$watch("myFynnyPropperty", function(newVal, oldVal) ...
```

But if you really want the watch to run only once, here is a way

```
var unregister = $scope.$watch("myFynnyPropperty", function(updatedproperty) {
    // do whatever you want to do
    console.log(updatedproperty);
    unregister();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong answer!

Editing, check out this article

[API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)

it looks like they are using a newvalue / oldvalue format

```
$scope.$watchCollection('names', function(newNames, oldNames) {
    $scope.dataCount = newNames.length;
});
```